# Are these two definitions of a line equivalent?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

> Let$~\mathbb{R}^2$ be equipped with the usual [Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), define a *line* to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is isometric to $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that all lines must be of the form $y=ax+b$ or be vertical(the more familiar definition)?

By definition a subset *l* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (equipped with the Euclidean metric) is said to be isometric to $\mathbb{R}$ iff there is a bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{R}\to l$ such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ , $|x-y|=d_E(f(x),f(y))$ (in other words there exists a bijection is which distance preserving). Here $d_{E}$ is the Euclidean metric.
I think the answer to the question is *yes*, I originally wanted to prove that a line(with the isometry definition) is uniquely determined by two points and I figured that this immediately follows if the answer to my question is "Yes".The proof(if this is true!) must use the Euclidean metric in *some fundamental way* because the theorem is not generally true, for instance it fails for the taxicab metric.

Comment: Just to be sure: what is your definition of "the Euclidean metric"? (there are several ones, e.g the Riemannian one, the vectorial one, the supremum of all "distance" of piecewise-affine paths joining two points, etc.)

Comment: @Didier Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: What is different about the Euclidean metric is that is comes from an inner product.  You can prove this from any inner product.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Is this obvious from the theory of inner products? (I know very little linear algebra)

Comment: It is not obvious from inner products. It is part of the lore of differential geometry. There are two types of metrics. You are talking about *topological* metrics - whose definition was boiled down to the minimum needed to define topological concepts, particularly limits. But geometry is more than topology, and you need a stricter concept of distance, one that also supports parallelism and angles. Inner products do this, topological metrics do not.

Comment: *Wow a downvote after 3 months*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl; dr Yes, this is true. Intuitively, if $\ell$ is not a line, there exist three non-collinear points on $\ell$, which is incompatible with $\ell$ being the image of an isometry.

---

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$One (standard) proof is to let $\ell$ be an arbitrary line, and to fix a distance-preserving bijection $f:\Reals \to \ell$. Pick distinct points $p$ and $q$ of $\ell$ arbitrarily, and let $L$ denote the Euclidean line through $p$ and $q$. Finally, let $v$ be the unit vector parallel to the displacement $q - p$, and let $n$ be either of the two unit vectors orthogonal to $v$. (This is where we're using the Euclidean metric and its origins with an inner product.)

It suffices to show the image of $f$ is contained in $L$.

By hypothesis, there exist real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $p = f(a)$ and $q = f(b)$. By exchanging the names of $p$ and $q$ if necessary, we may assume $a < b$ without loss of generality. The isometry condition on $f$ implies $t_{0} - a = d_{E}(p, f(t_{0}))$ and $b - t_{0} = d_{E}(f(t_{0}), q)$ provided $a \leq t_{0} \leq b$.

Introduce real-valued functions
$$
f_{1}(t) = (f(t) - p) \cdot v,\qquad
f_{2}(t) = (f(t) - p) \cdot n.
$$
Geometrically, we're resolving $f$ into components with the origin at $p$ and the Cartesian axes parallel to $v$ and to $n$, respectively. It suffices to show $f_{2}$ is identically $0$.

If $t_{0}$ is an arbitrary real number in $(a, b)$, then since $b - a = (t_{0} - a) + (b - t_{0})$ and $f$ is an isometry,
\begin{align*}
  d_{E}(p, q) &= d_{E}(p, f(t_{0})) + d_{E}(f(t_{0}), q) \\
  &= \bigl[(f_{1}(t_{0}) - a)^{2} + f_{2}(t_{0})^{2}\bigr]^{1/2}
  + \bigl[(b - f_{1}(t_{0}))^{2} + f_{2}(t_{0})^{2}\bigr]^{1/2} \\
  &\geq |f_{1}(t_{0}) - a| + |b - f_{1}(t_{0})| \geq b - a = d_{E}(p, q);
\end{align*}
consequently, the inequalities are equalities, and the first implies $f_{2}(t_{0}) = 0$. (The second can be used to show $f_{1}(t) = t - a$, so that $f$ is an affine parametrization of $\ell$.)

We conclude that the image of $[a, b]$ is contained in $L$. Since $p$ and $q$ were arbitrary points of $\ell$, we have $\ell \subset L$.

The reverse inclusion is easier: If $p$ is an arbitrary point of $L$, then $d_{E}(f(0), p) = r$ is a real number. If $r = 0$, then $p = f(0) \in \ell$. Otherwise, there are precisely two points of $L$ at Euclidean distance $r$ from $f(0)$, one of them being $p$, and precisely two real numbers of absolute value $r$. Since $f:\Reals \to \ell$ is a bijection, we have either $p = f(r)$ or $p = f(-r)$. In either case, $p \in \ell$.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate on the part where you say "this is where were using the Euclidean metric ..."

Comment: There's no notion of "orthogonality" with respect to a general metric, so this step does not make sense in, e.g., the taxicab metric.

Comment: Hmmm... Is there a reason we can't talk about angles in a sensible way in other metrics?

Comment: We might think of _angle_ as a numerical measure on the "space of directions". This presumes a notion of "directions" (such as unit tangent vectors, or unit displacements) and a means of comparing pairs of directions. When we're in an inner product, the set of linear transformations preserving the inner product acts transitively on directions at a point, while for other metrics this is not generally the case (perhaps not ever, depending how broadly we construe "metrics").

Answer (score 2):

Andrew D. Hwang's answer gives the basics, but I thought I'd add a few notes about the difference between topological metrics and geometric metrics.

In Euclidean space, suppose you have three points $O, A, B$. Draw the line $l$ parallel to $\overline{OA}$ and passing through $B$. Draw the circle of radius $d(O, A)$ with center $B$. It will intersect $l$ in two points $C$ and $D$, where $C$ is the point on the same side of the line through $O$ and $B$ as $A$, and $D$ is on the other side.

The Euclidean metric satisfies this identity, sometimes called the parallelogram law:

$$d(O,C)^2 + d(O,D)^2 = 2(d(O, A)^2 + d(O,B)^2)$$

$d(O,D) = d(A, B)$, so this law states that the sum of the squares of the diagonals of a parallelogram is equal to twice the sum of the squares of the sides.

For any metric that satisfies this law, you can treat $O$ as the origin, and all points as vectors from $O$. Then $C = B + A, D = B - A$, and for any point $P, d(O,P) = \|P\|$. The identity becomes
$$\|B + A\|^2 + \|B - A\|^2 = 2(\|A\|^2 + \|B\|^2)$$

Further, you can define $$\langle A, B\rangle := \frac 12\left(\|B + A\|^2 - \|B - A\|^2\right)$$
and this will turn out to be an inner product.

A metric on Euclidean space that satisfies the parallelogram law will define the lines of Euclidean geometry by the means you and Andrew have discussed. A metric that does not satisfy the parallelogram law does not respect the concepts of angle and parallelism in Euclidean geometry, and you do not get lines from them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "doesn't respect the concept of angle and parellelism ..."

Comment: Not a whole lot beyond the fact that the parallelogram law indicates the metric respects the parallelogram. I am hinting at some matters from differential geometry, but to explain them properly would require extensive foundations that I cannot build in a few comments.